# Problema de indexacion en google search Console

Tags: dominio, blogger

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando indexar en google mi pagina [www.javierheras.net](http://www.javierheras.net) que pero me esta dando la pagina principal error de redireccion, no entiendo porque da ese error si es que tenemos algo mal puesto en las dns de google o hay algo mal configurado en el blogger

Comment: ¿Es un dominio nuevo? ¿Qué tiene que ver Blogger aquí si parecería un dominio propio? ¿Las URLs que aparecen en la primera imagen navegan bien o producen error?

Comment: si navegar navega bien con esa url, accede sin problemas al blogger y sus entradas, lo que entiendo es porque me da error de indexacion con error de redireccion, digo a lo mejor puede ser que los dns del dominio que no esten bien configurados, que raro

Comment: Sigo sin entender lo de Blogger ¿? ¿Acaso estás redirigiendo de tu dominio a Blogger o algo así? Y, pregunté si el dominio era nuevo, porque si es nuevo la propagación suele tardar unas 48 horas para que esté visible en todo el mundo. Por otra parte, en la imagen se ven dos URL específicas con problemas, me refería con mi comentario a si **esas dos URL** navegan bien. Convendría también crear un sitemap que incluya las URL que quieres indexar e indicarle a Search Console dónde está ese sitemap, suele estar en el directorio raíz del dominio, bajo el nombre `sitemap.xml`